# App Crashes on Opening

Tags: iphone, xcode

I have an app that keeps crashing as soon as it starts. Not sure why. I have image views and buttons in the main xib file. The main xib file is not mainwindow, it is firstview, so i changed it in the plist to the firstview. There may be something wrong with the xib file for firstview but it only has buttons and images and a view in the back. There are no warnings or errors when I run it, just Debugging Terminated when it crashes.

Comment: what is the error in the console?

Comment: Run the application in debug mode, open the console and come back with the error message that's being logged.

Comment: If it crashes, you must have a warning or an error. Post the warning/error please and maybe someone will be able to help you :)

Comment: It just says "debugging terminated" but no warnings or errors in any file including xib files.

Answer (score 0):

To Debug a crash problem, especially on a small application, do a binary search on removing functionality and adding it back in until you find the smallest thing that when removed makes the crash go away, and when added back in causes the crash.   Sometimes this bottom-up search approach is easier than the top-down analytical approach to finding what is the problem.   Then when you know *what* is causing the problem, it's generally much easier to focus on *why* it is causing a problem.

Comment: Yeah I tried removing everything piece by piece but it kept crashing and i dont know what else to remove.

Comment: if absolutely nothing is left, then start with a blank new project and add things in one by one.

Answer (score 0):

What's the very last change you made before your app started crashing? That's the one that caused your problem. If you made a lot of changes at once before running your app to test them, now you know what that's a Very Bad Idea (tm)... :-(

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to switch it back to mainWindow, and then add the view as a subview in the app delegate did finish launching.  also, you may want to set a break point on obj_c_exception_throw.